# Erro IIS 7.5 carregamento de arquivos CSS e JS, Erro 403.14 no diretório.

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, iis-7

Fiz uma publicação de um projeto asp.net mvc 5 em um servidor com Windows Server 2008 r2 e IIS 7.5, ao tentar executar a aplicação ela não carrega os arquivos css e js.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Onde que no meu projeto os arquivos estão lá com os nomes corretos.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obs: Foco no erro 403.

Não se o pq os arquivos estão pegando esses nomes nem de ondem, alguém me ajuda por favor!!!!???

Comment: Cara só para te dar uma luz, isso está com cara de problema com seus bundle, tenta publicar o site em modo debug para ver se ele consegue subir tudo.

Comment: Pelo modo de debud apareceu perfeitamente, obrigado pela dica. Agora vc saberia me dizer o q ocasiona o erro quando o publish e feito em modo release ?

Comment: então, o problema realmente está nos seus bundles =] vou pedir para que poste o código do mesmo para que possa tentar localizar o problema. Por default o vs coloca seu arquivo de bundle dentro da pasta App_Start/BundleConfig.cs